# How can I determine which class a JMock mock object is mocking?

Tags: java, unit-testing, guice, jmock

Say I've got a mock setup like this:

```java
JUnit4Mockery context = new JUnit4Mockery();
MyInterface mock = context.mock(MyInterface.class);
```

And later I want to examine my mock object to find out what class it's mocking:

```java
Class mockedClass = mock.??? //would return MyInterface.class
```

I didn't see anything obvious in the JMock (2.5.1) javadocs about how to do this - the signature for the `mock` method is

```java
<T> T mock (Class<T> typeToMock)
```

In previous versions (I looked at 1.2.0) you would create a `Mock` object directly, and one of its methods was

```java
Class getMockedType()
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a unit testing framework for using DI inside my unit tests.  (I'm using Guice 3.0.)  Having DI in the tests is a restriction of the application server/platform I'm working with - the objects I'm testing are subclasses of a multiton that has its own `Injector`, which is what I'm trying to populate.

I'd prefer not to have to create an anonymous instance of AbstractModule in every test, so I'm trying to build something like this (this seems like it would have worked in 1.2):

```java
public class MockModule extends AbstractModule {
    private Iterable<Mock> mocks;

    public MockModule(Iterable<Mock> mocks) {
        this.mocks = mocks;
    }

    protected void configure() {
        for (Mock mock : mocks) {
            bind(mock.getMockedType()).toInstance(mock);
        }
    }
}
```

The only thing missing is the answer (if there is one) to this question.

**RESPONSE TO ACCEPTED ANSWER**

Here is what I ended up creating for this use case:

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
public class MockModule extends AbstractModule {
    private final Iterable mocks;

    public MockModule(Object mock) {
        mocks = Lists.newArrayList(mock);
    }

    public MockModule(Iterable mocks) {
        this.mocks = mocks;
    }

    protected void configure() {
        for (Object mock : mocks) {
            Class superclass = mock.getClass().getSuperclass();
            if (superclass != Object.class && superclass != Proxy.class) {
                bind(superclass).toInstance(mock);
                continue;
            }
            Class[] interfaces = mock.getClass().getInterfaces();
            if (interfaces.length > 0) {
                bind(interfaces[0]).toInstance(mock);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Class mockedClass = mock.getClass().getInterfaces()[0];
System.out.println("Class is " + mockedClass.getCanonicalName());
```

Will print:

```
Interface is MyInterface
```

There are possibly more robust ways to do it, but it gets the job done for this particular JMock version at least.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll wait to see if someone can suggest a more robust version, but this will definitely get me pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Another approach might be to create a custom Imposteriser that adds an extra interface to the mock objects to query for their class.

Comment: I really like that idea...I'll look into it.

Comment: I ended up using this solution, with a couple of extra checks for `class` mock binding.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your motivations for doing this. JMock is conventionally used to unit test an object, or small cluster of objects, which means that everything is new'ed up in the test. DI usually kicks in at the level of integration or acceptance testing, when exercising something that looks more like a real component.

What are you trying to show by using DI within the tests?

Comment: The objects I'm testing use a Guice `Injector` internally (it's a service provided by their subclass).  I *must* populate the injector with my mocks in order to test them.  I'm still only testing the direct dependencies of the objects; it's just that the objects themselves are not created using DI, but rather consume DI for our sanity.

Comment: I haven't seen the code, but my standard response is that the tests are trying to tell you something about the design...

Comment: I agree completely - ask my team lead how much I complain.  However, the creation of these objects is out of my control at runtime, so it's a win just to get DI in at all in my opinion.